# How can i read emails using Graph api without manual intervention for browser login/authorization?

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api

All i wanted to run a python script to read email from office365 using `graph-api`.
Everywhere i can see that examples with browser interaction for getting the accessToken.

i have tried with these steps in https://dzone.com/articles/getting-access-token-for-microsoft-graph-using-oau . Retrieved the Access token successfully. But when try to access https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages with access token ended up with `"code":"BadRequest","message":"/me request is only valid with delegated authentication flow."`.

[image]

Can someone help me with proper guidance or available examples.

Comment: Looks like you set application type permissions and you cannot call /me/messages endpoint. You need to call /users/{user_id}/messages endpoint.

Comment: updated the question, I tried `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/`

returns `Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.`

Comment: Try to add Application type permission instead Delegated in Azure

Comment: can you explain bit more. i am new to this.

Comment: You are sharing a screenshot of Permissions you have set in Azure portal. In Type column I see that the type of permissions is Delegated but it should be Application type. You (or your tenant admin) must add Application type of Mail.Read, Mail.ReadBasic and User.Read permissions.

Comment: @user2250152 why it should be Application instead of Delegated? I got the following piece from the documentation: "Calling the /me endpoint requires a signed-in user and therefore a delegated permission. Application permissions are not supported when using the /me endpoint."  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: @basquiatraphaeu I guess that I suggested to add application type because the screenshot was missing and it wasn't clear what type of permissions was set.